# MCE Injection on QEMU

Tags: qemu

QEMU has a build in mechanism for MCE injection.
However the mechanism is not perfect, QEMU just fills MCA registers with partial data and then triggers MCE.

I want to add a real corruption before triggering MCE.

The first thing which I tried is to add all MSRs as described in Intel Software Developer's Manual, however it seems that the guest OS is still not aware of the new registers that I have add.

I did the following:
1. Added the MSRs in CPUX86State.
2. Added support for reading the new MSRs in helper_rdmsr & helper_wrmsr.

Why the guest OS still unaware of these MSRs?

I also tried to corrupt the EIP before triggering MCE, but the guest OS just crashed without arriving to MCE handler.

In my understanding the MCE handler is exactly to deal with such errors.
What I'm I missing?

Comment: I didn't use KVM. What do you mean dummy? I did see many of the MCA registers implemented in qemu including banks. I also injected an error and triggered MCE and crash.

Comment: In order for the OS to support MCE, few registers should be configured (MCi_CTL and relevant CPUID fields), beside that when error detected HW set relevant registers with data that indicate that #MC has happened (MCi_STATUS)